# Google Sheets API Something went wrong. Please try again

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm rying to ENABLE THE GOOGLE SHEETS API on an existing projects.

I am following the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

But when I click the blue button, select existing project from dropdown and click NEXT, it gives me an error: 
[image: screenshot]

Also, there is an error in console:

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:148 POST https://clientauthconfig.clients6.google.com/v1/brands?alt=json&key=key 400
```

Also, the error does not show up when instead of selecting an existing project, I create a new one.

Comment: This popup window will show when an existing project has not enabled the Google Sheets API. If an existing project has enabled the API the popup will not show. You will need to follow the docs and create a new project or just simply enable the API directly from https://console.developers.google.com.